# Reading very large text files in java

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I'm using the following code to read large files:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FilePath));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while ((cur = br.readLine()) != null)
```

I'm able to read large files using above code but I want to know how these readers works internally in memory. What role does inputstreamreader plays? How many chunks of memory gets allocated while reading a file(e.g 2 GB) line by line?

Comment: look at the source.

Comment: Source as in javadocs? I already went through that. My confusion is how the inputstreamreader and bufferedreader are linked

Comment: a bufferedReader needs a source to read from. That is the only *link* there is.

Comment: So does that mean isr will keep on supplying the character streams to br and bufferedreader will store that in buffer? If thats the case how many characters does isr read(reads bytes and decodes them into characters) in one go from file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InputStreamReader is a facility to convert a raw InputStream (stream of bytes) to a stream of characters, according to some charset. FIleInputStream is a stream of bytes (it extends InputStream) from a given file. You can use InputStreamReader to read text, for instance, from a socket as well, as socket.getInputStream() also gives an InputStream.

InputStreamReader is a Reader, the abstract class for a stream of characters. Using an InputStreamReader alone would be inefficient, as each "readLine" would actually read from the file. When you decorate with a BufferedReader, it will read a chunk of bytes and keep it in memory, and use it for subsequent reads.

About the size: the documentation does not state the default value:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

> The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used. The
>   default is large enough for most purposes.

You must check the source file to find the value.

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java

This is the implementation in the OpenJDK:

```
 private static int defaultCharBufferSize = 8192;
```

The Oracle's closed source JDK implementation may be different.

Comment: you should probably mention that this is from JDK7

Comment: How does fileinputstream stream gets the stream of bytes from the input file?

Comment: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/FileInputStream.java

Take a look at the code. It needs to communicate with the JVM for inter-operating with the host operating system. It's not easy to guess how it is done.

Comment: And also there's native (C or C++)  code :

 private native void open(String name) throws FileNotFoundException;

Comment: It's better for you understanding the Reader/InputStream abstractions, and how the Java API uses decorators for enriching their basic functionality.

Comment: If fileinputstream will keep on generating stream of bytes in RAM for Inputstreamreader to decode then how come we don't run out of memory while reading large file?

Comment: Because you will read pieces of the file each time, keeping them on Strings or a byte[] array, and those pieces will be garbage collected as they are no longer necessary.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot!